# Behaviour of variables projected out of the sub-select

Tags: sparql

Given a list of entities (with Persons among them) and their properties how should the following query behave:

```
select *
where
{

    ?s ?p ?o.
    {
            SELECT ?ps WHERE
            {
                    ?ps a <http://www.example.org/schema/Person> .
            }
            limit 1
    }
    #?ps ?p ?o.

    filter (?s =?ps)
}
```

I tested this in 3 triple stores. Two of them filter on ps with the above query so the result is triples for one person(+ps column).

The 3'rd one returns all database triples because "The variable "ps" that is projected out of the sub-select does not join with anything in the top-level query."

Still since it's projected out and I use it in a FILTER I would expect to apply the filter.

Uncommenting line " #?ps ?p ?o. " will indeed display triples for  one person.

Comment: Since an answer has been posted that states that the filter should be applied, can you provide more details about what triple stores you've tested against?   Questions about code should provide enough to reproduce, and while it might not be possible to share all your data, telling us what triple stores you're testing against might help in figuring out _why_ one is giving you different results.  Perhaps it doesn't fully support SPARQL 1.1 (which introduced subqueries), and this is one of the places where the incomplete support is observed?

Comment: While trying to solve my other problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977711/how-to-implement-pagination-in-sparql) I ran queries over Systap bigdata 1.3, stardog 2, brighstardb all latest versions and support sparql 1.1. The problem is with bigdata and I submitted a ticket [here](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/bigdata/ticket/796); it also contains sample data file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter will be applied.

The FILTER applies to the whole block.  There is a join of results of "?s ?p ?o" with results ?ps (so it's a join that is a cross product at this point - no common variable - but that's OK).  That results in solutions with 4 bindings ?s ?p ?o ?ps  The filter then applies.

You could write:

```
WHERE {
  ?s ?p ?o.
  {
       SELECT ?s 
       WHERE { ?s a <http://www.example.org/schema/Person> . }
       limit 1
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware it could be improved but I just extracted the sample query from another query so the improvement can only apply here.